# Writing a test for a conditional block in a reducer/action creator

Tags: javascript, reactjs, testing, enzyme

Say I have a reducer or action creator that has some conditional logic in it and depending on the logic it will either call window.location.assign or dispatches an action. how can I mock out/change the `const` (which is local to the function) which causes it to either jump into the if or else block

literally googled so much for this and cannot find it anywhere. anyone got any ideas? even pointing me to docs

literally all I want to test is:

```
const url = getState().url
if(url){
  window.location... // one test for this
} else {
  dispatch({ type: MY_ACTION }) //a second test for this
}
```

why the heck is it so hard to find any docs or examples on this

Comment: Why don't you mock `getState()`?

Comment: @TobiasR. how do I mock it? jest tells me I can only mock functions. this is an object

Comment: `getState()` is a function which returns an object with a field named url.

Comment: oh yeh obv (dam). so I can do this: `const getState = jest.fn()
getState.mockReturnValue(false)` and then change it to true for the other side of the conditional?

Comment: I never worked with jest. Just mock `getState()` inside your tests and let it return the desired object. :)

Comment: yeh I did that but cant get it to work unfortunately :( it does sound like it should work tho

Comment: You maybe should add the code which tries to mock `getState()`